# SSRS regional format running inside Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have SSRS running in integration mode inside of sharepoint.  When developing SSRS reports we are able to set the date and number formats to recognize regional settings and format appropriately.  But when the report is deployed to SSRS the regional formats all revert back to us.  Is there a way to have this display properly inside of Sharepoint?

Answer (score 2):

We have written an external DLL that SSRS uses. We pass the value that we want converted (for example a date) and a Region Code/Culture setting. When we create the reports, all the reports have the region format as a parameter.

The reason for this is there is no way for SSRS to get the region from the client web browser, plus we wanted the users to be able to explicitly set what the region code they want for display.

Here is an [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/balajiintel/CustomAssemblyinRS06302005081435AM/CustomAssemblyinRS.aspx?ArticleID=f3904516-e30a-401a-aa01-463636d78f18) on using a custom assembly for SSRS.

Let me know if you want more background.